# android kitkat webview client certificate authentication

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

In my current android project i need to support client certificate authentication for android 4.4(kitkat) webview.
Before kitkat ClientCertRequestHandler and WebViewClientClassicExt classes were there to support client certificate authentication but in 4.4 release these classes are removed.

So is there any way keystore or reflection or any other way to support client certificate authentication in android 4.4 webview.

Comment: How do you managed to use WebViewClientClassicExt class ?